# How to include a checkbox in a windows 8 dialog?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, windows-8

I am currently working on a win 8 app.

And for one my of dialogs I want to include checkbox for "don't show me this message again". I looked at the msdn documentation for Windows.UI.Popups but could not find the information I want.

How do I include a checkbox?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible -- the built in `MessageDialog` class doesn't provide for that level of customization. You will need to build your own flyout based control.

Comment: Thanks! Right now, I am just gonna use the default dialog and work on customizing one later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add new elements in the *MessageDialog*

If you use HTML5/javascript app. You can make you own "Windows Store" dialog style. With CSS and to  place a checkbox, use this code:

```
<input type="checkbox">value</input>
```